# Does Finder preview interfere with file I/O from a running code?

Tags: finder, preview, file

I've found the preview feature of Finder and other file management programs (like Forklift3) to be very useful for checking the progress of a calculation. For example, if I have a code continuously modify a certain file, I can gauge how close it is to completion. However, if the file is visible in preview, can it potentially interfere with the file I/O of the program when the file is being modified?

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:preview] referring to Preview.app, which is a separate app to Finder and other macOS apps; are you actually referring to [tag:quicklook] or am I misunderstanding what Finder ‘preview feature’ you're using?

Comment: @grgarside I'm referring to the preview panel in Finder accessible in View→Show Preview, not the separate Preview app.